# spring-boot Testing Error 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to write light weight spring restful services, 
I'd prefer to write TDD application, so did not used server to run the application. 
I used eclipse with "maven test" and "Junit test".

Please help me find the cause response 404 in spring boot application.
Here is the Application

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/")
        String home() {
            return "welcome";
        }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
  }

}
```

The restful services testing code is as follow

```
 import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
  import org.junit.Test;
  import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
  import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
  import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
  import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
  import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
  import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("welcome")));
    }
    }
```

Did i miss something configuration for MockHttpServletResponse ? As the output error is

```
mydemo
com.sample.mydemo.ExampleTest
getHello(com.sample.mydemo.ExampleTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>   at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)  at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)  at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:664) at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)   at com.sample.mydemo.ExampleTest.getHello(ExampleTest.java:30)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:250)   at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:189)    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: I think you are missing basic annotations in your Example class. How will spring know that it has to look up there.. I think you may have to annotate the class with @RestController or other annotations based on the Spring version

Comment: It worked! when @RestController is added 
thank you,

Comment: Glad it worked, please up vote my comment if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your code you are missing the name of application to run for test, e.g.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = Example.class
)
```

it will start spring boot application first with Context and then run your test. In case you need to start spring boot application for testing on the same port which is configured for main application you can use this code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = Example.class,
        webEnvironment = DEFINED_PORT
)
```